# customize tab bar (need a guidance)

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I saw some app have the following tab bar:

[image]

I summarize the above tab bar with following characteristics:

1. showing on top
2. not fully occupy the full screen width
3. Inside an navigation controller

(I am using xcode8 + swift3)

I would like to implement the same thing, but I don't know how to do it (I know how to implement default tab bar showing at bottom & occupy full screen width). Could someone please guide me or provide a tutorial link how to implement this thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a UISegmentedControl and not a tab bar.

Read more about it here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol

Here is a link on how to use it https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/segmented-control-tutorial-ios10